# How to target an h1 inside an <a>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the `div` to change background when hovered on. But it doesn't change background when the text inside the `div` is hovered on instead.
This is what I tried, but ALL the background `div`s change. I also tried `a > img` instead of just `img` in my handler functions, but it didn't work at all.

```
function handlerIn() {
    $("img").css({"opacity":1});
}

function handlerOut() {
    $("img").css({"opacity":0});
}

$("a").mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

Comment: This OP contains 3 questions - 1.) How to target an h1 inside an <a>? 2.) I want the div to change background when hovered on. 3.) I also tried a > img instead of just img in my handler functions, but it didn't work at all.
Which one is it?

Comment: To be clear, the OP's event handlers are triggering for all `img` elements. They want to only trigger the element that the user activated using mouseenter/mouserleave.

Comment: what's the h1 inside an a got to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

`a > img` does not work because `img` is not a child of `a` (`parent > child`)  but a descendant (`achestor descendant`).

So your css rule should look like this:

```
a:hover  img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

So you don't need jQuery at all, but if you want to use jQuery then you need to use the `a` element where the event happens as root for our search for the `img` element otherwise you will find all `img` elements.

```
function handlerIn() {
  $(this).find('img').css({
    "opacity": 1
  });
}

function handlerOut() {
  $(this).find('img').css({
    "opacity": 0
  });
}

$("a").mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery to done the job.

It can be done by css:

```
#kpop:hover, #fashion:hover, #martialarts:hover, #nature:hover{
  background: url('http://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image_preview');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this correct why you don't use **`hover()`** function?
http://codepen.io/soulister/pen/MyZrPy

Comment: `hover` is just a short form of  `.mouseenter( ... ).mouseleave( ... );` and it would not make a difference if you use one or the the other. And before you changed your code from `$("img").css({"opacity":1});` to  `$(this).find("img").css({"opacity":1});`  it didn't work either, so the solution is not the `hover()` but the `$(this).find("img")`. And if you write an answer then please include your code within the answer and not just link to it.